# Change loop max value during process

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Let's say that I have a simple loop which looks like following:

```
Dim iCounter as Long
Dim iMax as Long
    iMax = 4

For iCounter = 1 to iMax
    If iCounter = 3 Then iMax = 5
    Debug.Print iCounter
Next iCounter
```

The question now is, why I cannot change my iMax on runtime? The result of this operation would be values from 1 to 4, but not 5.

Is there a way how to change this without using a GoTo statement to the beginning of the loop and without changing the looping logic? (I can do this with Do - While loop, but I wanted to know if I can do the same with this one)

Comment: does this work `if iCounter=iMax then exit for`

Comment: is the purpose just to skip he iteration of 4 and move onto the next one?

Comment: It is never a good idea to change loop counters in a loop other than by the loop itself. The ending value of a counted loop is set when the For statement is first encountered and cannot be changed after that. So you will need to revisit your logic. Please try to explain what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub t()

Dim iMax As Integer
Dim iCounter As Integer

iMax = 10

For iCounter = 1 To iMax

    If iCounter = iMax Then Exit For
    If iCounter = 5 Then iMax = 8

Next iCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable that gets incremented on each loop. Then if you want to add, change icounter to icounter - 1